# Map x number of DateTimes against set List of TimeSpans

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, f#, sequence

I'm trying to build a sequence of DateTimes that is X elements in length going back in time but falling only on certain TimeSpans. These TimeSpans are the result of a calculation of valid TimeSpans between 2 ranges and a supplied step interval. I start by calculating this list of TimeSpans using the following:

```
let timeSpans (rangeBottom: TimeSpan) (rangeTop: TimeSpan) (step: TimeSpan) =
    let isInsideRange (timeStamp: TimeSpan) =
        timeStamp >= rangeBottom && timeStamp < rangeTop

    let validTimes = list<TimeSpan>.Empty

    let rec checkTime (timeStamp:TimeSpan) (times: list<TimeSpan>) =
        if (isInsideRange(timeStamp)) then
            checkTime (timeStamp + step) (list.Cons(timeStamp, times))
        else
            list.Cons(rangeTop, times)
    checkTime rangeBottom validTimes
```

So given a rangeBottom of 10AM and a rangeTop of 11AM and a step of 12 minutes I would generate a list of valid TimeSpans that contains the values `[11:00:00; 10:48:00; 10:36:00; 10:24:00; 10:12:00; 10:00:00]`

Now, given a DateTime which is my starting point, I would like to map that against my list of TimeSpans cyclically X number of times starting from the closest TimeSpan from the list.

So if my staring point was today at 10:50, and I was looking for 8 values the resulting sequence that I would like to build is `today 10:48, today 10:36, today 10:24, today 10:12, today 10:00, yesterday 11:00, yesterday 10:48, yesterday 10:36`

I'm driving myself crazy trying to cyclically reuse the TimeSpans against days falling backwards, can anyone point me in the right direction? My code here is in F# but if someone can understand the problem and help me solve it using LINQ in C# I'd gladly convert it over.

Comment: I would start off by using different data types. The fact that you have a `TimeSpan` with a name `timeStamp` sounds *very* fishy to me. You might want to use Noda Time (http://nodatime.org) to give you some more consistent and expressive date/time concepts.

Comment: @JonSkeet You're right, bad naming on my part for the timeStamp. I've taken a look at your noda time library in the past and it does look very interesting, however this project is for work and at this point switching Time libraries would be outside the scope of the problem as it would take quite a bit to convince the powers that be to do so when we have so much code that would need to be changed

Comment: Even if you can't use Noda Time for the final solution, I suspect you'll find it simpler to prototype that solution using clearer types. At the moment I don't know what those "valid TimeSpans" are meant to be - are they really "time of day" values?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes they are simply a time of day that I would like to map against dates going backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want.

The `repeat` function turns your times and start date into a never ending `Seq` of `DateTime`, that you can then `Seq.skipWhile` and `Seq.take` to get the right starting point and number of items.

```
let times = timeSpans (TimeSpan.FromHours(10.)) (TimeSpan.FromHours(11.)) (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(12.))
let startDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(10.).AddMinutes(50.)

let rec repeat (date:DateTime) times = 
    seq { 
        yield! times |> Seq.map (fun t -> date.Date.Add(t)); 
        yield! repeat (date.AddDays(-1.0)) times }

times 
|> repeat startDate
|> Seq.skipWhile (fun dt -> dt > startDate)
|> Seq.take 8
|> Seq.toArray
```

Comment: After playing around with this for a day I gotta say thank you! I had never fully understand the yield! keyword before and this is very elegant for my use case. Would upvote twice if I could

Comment: Welcome. I sometimes explain `yield!` to other C# devs as similar to `SelectMany`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work.

```
let times : seq<TimeSpan> = ... //computed using your function
let timesRepeating = seq { while true do yield! times }
let dates = seq<DateTime> = ... //your list of dates
let datesRepeating = 
  seq { for date in dates do
          for _ in times do
            yield date }

Seq.zip datesRepeating timesRepeating
|> Seq.map (fun (date, time) -> date.Add(time))
```